# How to log in automatically or programmatically to Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I have a computer that is used for getting database information from the server in the same domain, and this computer is used by employees who don't have the server admin information.

When the computer restarts, I'd like it to automatically log in to Windows Server so that it can access the database files. Is it possible to write a script for this that runs on boot?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Janes I can use another account with below admin permissions, but the question is the same.

Comment: Because the point is that they shouldn't have to log in.

Comment: Maybe I worded the question poorly. The computer itself is not the Windows Server, it's a regular Windows 10 PC. However it needs to log in to the Windows Server (using the dashboard) to access the shared files located on the server. My goal is that this should be done automatically whenever the PC restarts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by adding the credentials to the Credentials Manager in Windows, along with disabling the Windows Server dashboard program. This makes Windows automatically log in to the server with the stored credentials on boot.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question really isn't specific, I'd like to suggest two ways of accomplishing your goal.

1. Since you'd like to access database information, why not use some kind of database management software (like SSMS if you're using MSSQL) and set up proper permissions for the user/computer that will need to obtain information from that particular server/database.
2. If you need access to raw files (which doesn't make much sense in case of MSSQL for accessing purposes), why not set up proper permissions on the file or parent folder, giving the user that is logged to the client PC proper permissions to access the files that are of interest.